# how to see if someone has marked my email id as spam?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

Is there any any to find if someone has marked my email id as spam? both mail ids are gmail id.

Comment: For regular email addresses, using regular email software, mrdenny's "no, there isn't" is correct. Online services such as Gmail would probably not offer any way to figure this out either (if only to keep spammers from changing addresses), but such online services are off-topic on Super User anyway, or the answers would be too subjective for Super User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible to gather data from all computers in the world, you wouldn't be able to have an answer. My spam filter (Mail.app on Mac OS X) filters some kinds of messages from a given email but let others be visible. Many filters consider not only email id but message contents as well.